# About XML declaration

Tags: xml

For example like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

I want to know when this xsd file downloaded

If my computer is not connected to internet
I thought my computer can't read this xml file.
because my computer can't download xsd file

but my computer diplay this xml file
why?

what is xsd for?

My English so... not good.
sorry.

Answer (score 0):

XSD is used when you ask an XML parser to validate a document's structure against the schemas which describe that kind of document.

If you don't request validation, the parser will not insist on retrieving the schema and will only check that the document is "well-formed", meaning that it's syntactically correct XML. Note that without validation against the schema, none of the type information that the schema defines will be available, only the basic XML data model.

Comment: so... based on your concept, I've tested my web application. I've modified my web application context xml file. xsd to xx. and server started. I thought when was server start, was should down load xsd